# Separate columns for text and code/output in Markdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am writing a small exercise book with Markdown. I would like to have the final output with the plots on a column and the document text on the other. Similar problems are addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237190/2-column-report-in-r-markdown-render-html-aside-data-frame) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717323/align-two-data-frames-next-to-each-other-with-knitr?lq=1). Unfortunately, they mainly desire one output per column. I would like to produce the output on a column and the text on the other. Really interesting is [Docco](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/vignettes/docco-classic.html), but it apprently shows the code output with the text.

A possible solution would be the [RPres](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486468-Authoring-R-Presentations) markdown horizontal rule: using `***`, it creates two easy to use columns. But I do find documentation on its implementation in Markdown documents.

Here an image showing my results so far and an example of my code:

[image]

````
```{r setoption, cache=TRUE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.width=12}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.width=4,     echo = FALSE)
```

```{r, loadlibraries}
library(knitr)
library(lattice)
```

### Exercise 1 - 22/4/'16

 Is the data set shown in the following figure symmetric or skewed? How many modes does this data set have?

```{r 1.1}
e1 <- rep(seq(1, 6, 1), c(6, 4, 2, 2, 4, 6))
barchart(table(e1), horizontal = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "Frequency")
```
**Solution:**
The data set is symmetric. Furthermore, it has two modes.

### Exercise 2 - 22/4/'16

Describe the shape of the dataset shown in the following figure.
```{r 2.1}
e2 <- rep(seq(1, 9, 1), c(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1))
barchart(table(e2), ylab = "Frequency", horizontal = FALSE)
```
**Solution:**
The dataset is right skewed, also said right skewed, with one mode.
````

Comment: You probably want the [reverse of this](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/graphics/)?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're asking for columns, my answer will be: table.

Using [`pipe_tables`](http://pandoc.org/README.html#extension-pipe_tables), figure and text can be alinged next to each other. However, this comes at a price:

> The cells of pipe tables cannot contain block elements like paragraphs and lists, and cannot span multiple lines.

If this limitation is acceptable, `pipe_tables` provide a quite straightforward solution:

````
```{r img, fig.show = "hide", echo = FALSE}
library(knitr)
hist(rnorm(1000))    
```

Figure|Explanation
-------------------------------|-------------------------
`r include_graphics(paste0(opts_chunk$get("fig.path"), "img-1.png"))`|Histogram of 1000 draws from a standard normal density.
````

[image: Result]

Although the column headers cannot be omitted, you can leave them blank if desired.

Note that I initially suppress the plot (`fig.show = "hide"`) and use `include_graphics` to include it afterwards. Otherwise, there would be a newline after the plot which disrupts the table.

(In knitr 1.12.3, `include_graphics` doesn't seem to work properly with inline code chunks. However, the current [development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#installation) 1.12.25 works well.)

## Extension

I hacked together an extension that allows to use a single chunk to generate and show the plots and some more features:

````
```{r setup, echo = FALSE}
library(knitr)
FigureNextToText <- function(number, # number of plot in chunk
                             text, 
                             alt = "", # alternative text for image
                             label = opts_current$get("label"), # set explicitly when using inline!
                             ext = ".png",
                             headerL = "&nbsp;", headerR = "&nbsp;", # empty string confuses pandoc if only right header is set
                             widthL = 30, widthR = 30,
                             ...) {
  path <- fig_chunk(label = label, ext = ext, number = number, ...)
  template <- "%s|%s
%s|%s
![%s](%s)|%s\r\n\r\n"
  output <- sprintf(
    template,
    headerL, headerR,
    paste0(rep("-", widthL), collapse = ""), paste0(rep("-", widthR), collapse = ""),
    alt, path, text
    )
  return(asis_output(output))
}
```

```{r img, fig.show = "hide", echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
library(knitr)
hist(rnorm(1000))
hist(runif(n = 1000, min = 0, max = 10))

FigureNextToText(1, text = "Histogram of draws from standard normal density.", widthL = 50, widthR = 10)
FigureNextToText(2, text = "Histogram of draws from uniform distribution.", headerR = "Explanation", alt = "Histogram 2.") 
```

Some text.

`r FigureNextToText(2, text = "The same plot, this time inline.", label = "img", headerR = "Explanation", alt = "Histogram 2.")`

Some more text.
````

[image: Output]

I know that the `setup` looks a little bit scary, but once `FigureNextToText` is defined, it can be called quite simply, e.g.:

```
FigureNextToText(2, text = "Histogram of draws from uniform distribution.", headerR = "Explanation", alt = "Histogram 2.")
```

Finding the correct values for `widthL` and `widthR` is somewhat cumbersome. This is because their effect depends on the number of characters in the cell, i.e. the filename of the image in the MD file and the `alt` text, too.

Comment: This approach is not just perfect.  Even if it is a little "hard", it is even beautiful. I tried to install the developer version, but it required a `pdfLatex` installation that apparently is no more at disposal. It appears to be a serious problem of my installation. Thank you anyway for your effort!

Comment: @Worice I added an extension that doesn't use `include_graphics` and should work without the developer version.

Comment: I am amazed by your work and competencies, it works really well! I think you should make this answer more widely accessible, perhaps by incorporate your code in a package?

Comment: @Worice Thank you; glad I could help. I think here on SO the code already is quite accessible. If others find it helpful, too, this answer will be upvoted, gaining even more attention. If not … then it wasn't helpful for too many others.