# Align multiple tables side by side

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

The following code produces 2 tables on top of each other. How would I set it to have them aligned side by side, e.g. 3 to a row?

````
---
title: "sample"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r global_options, R.options=knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)}
```   

```{r sample, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
t1 <- head(mtcars)[1:3]
t2 <- head(mtcars)[4:6]
print(kable(t1))
print(kable(t2))
```
````

Output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-have-two-tables-side-by-side

Comment: I saw that while researching how to do this. I do not understand the syntax; The top voted answer says "Just put two tabular environments side by side. Add spacing as desired." then shows some code with syntax like this: \begin{tabular}{ccc}. I don't know how I could apply that to the above example using mtcars tables?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Just put two data frames in a list, e.g.

```
t1 <- head(mtcars)[1:3]
t2 <- head(mtcars)[4:6]
knitr::kable(list(t1, t2))
```

Note this requires **knitr** >= 1.13.

Comment: Is it possible to use customized lines as with `xtable`?

Comment: No, but I think `kable(..., booktabs = TRUE)` and adding `tables: yes` in YAML (as a _top-level_ option) should give you what you want.

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot

Comment: Cheeky follow up, would there be an equally simple way to add spacing between the tables?

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with a Word document.  This answer stacks the tables vertically rather than side by side when I tried it (`output: word_document`).

Comment: @JeanV.Adams No, Word is not supported.

Comment: Is it possible to adjust the spacing between the to tables?

Comment: Interesting to note that when the tables are assigned to objects, and then fed as a list to a single `kable()` call and rendered in a pdf document, the default formatting is different to if the table is printed as the result of the last command of a chunk being `kable()` without assignment. The tables rendered from a list have cells fully outlined, while the tables which were not assigned have partially open cells in the body of the table.

Comment: If anyone is finding this approach breaking the $math$ rendering, try adding knitr::kable(escape = False).

Comment: Although `knitr::kable(list(t1, t2)) %>% kable_styling()` gives no errors, the result is like the entire table was made of a single line. :-(

Comment: @YihuiXie When I do this in a R markdown file the table doesn't appear between other writing but just goes to the top of the page.

Comment: Here's a major hack to put space between the tables in LaTeX.  Assign the result of `kable()` to a variable, say `foo`.  Now `foo[1]` is a character containing the latex (or html) that will be output.  You can then manipulate that string.  I did `foo[1] <- stringr::str_replace_all(foo[1],"\\\\end\\{tabular\\}","\\\\end{tabular}\\\\hfill")` and the same thing with begin to balance it.  Finally, just output `foo` on a line by itself.

Comment: the suggestion does not answer the question. the two tables may be unrelated and need different captions etc.

Answer (score 30):

I used this [Align two data.frames next to each other with knitr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717323/align-two-data-frames-next-to-each-other-with-knitr) which shows how to do it in `html` and this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-have-two-tables-side-by-side to align 2 Latex tables next to each other. It seems that you cannot freely adjust the lines of the table as you can do it with `xtable` (does anybody know more about this?). With `format = Latex` you get a horizontal line after each row. But the documentation shows two examples for other formats. One using the `longtable` package (additional argument: `longtable = TRUE`) and the other using the `booktabs` package (`booktabs = TRUE`).

````
---
title: "sample"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
---

```{r global_options, R.options=knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)}
```


```{r sample, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
library(xtable)

t1 <- kable(head(mtcars)[1:3], format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE)
t2 <- kable(head(mtcars)[4:6], format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE)

cat(c("\\begin{table}[!htb]
    \\begin{minipage}{.5\\linewidth}
      \\caption{}
      \\centering",
        t1,
    "\\end{minipage}%
    \\begin{minipage}{.5\\linewidth}
      \\centering
        \\caption{}",
        t2,
    "\\end{minipage} 
\\end{table}"
))  
```
````

[image]

Comment: Hi @Alex thanks for answering. I don't recognize the syntax e.g. begin{table}[!htb]. What is that? Is that R?

Comment: No that is Latex. If you write in rmarkdown and you are producing a PDF it does not work directly. It is first translated to Latex. The cool thing is that you can also use Latex directly and use its full power.

Comment: This is useful code, I have managed to create three rows of tables. Thanks! How would you add a space between the table and caption? Happy to open as a new question, if appropriate.

Comment: @user2716568 Simply put for example a `\\hspace{-1cm}` between `\\end{minipage}%
 \\begin{minipage}` (behind the %) if you want reduce the space by 1 cm. And I usually vote for an question or answer if I found it helpful or just interesting. However, this seems not to be common on Stack Overflow ... .

Comment: @ Moody_Mudskipper There should be a similar solution. But for this I would ask a new question.

Comment: I believe @Alex is using an approach which effectively returns from the R chunk text, which is then processed by LaTeX. This means that if you were to write the following inline: `\begin{table}[!htb]
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      \caption{}
      \centering,
       \`r t1\`,
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
        \caption{},
        \`r t2\`,
    \end{minipage} 
\end{table}` is almost functionally equivalent, except that the backticks around `t1` and `t2` are printed out before and after the tables. Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: I've created a full question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211887/how-can-the-backticks-printed-around-these-tables-be-escaped

Comment: I get the error `! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.` when I try to knit to PDF

Answer (score 27):

here a solution for **html documents**

(As this question was asked very broadly and not *specifically* referring to LaTeX).

Requires `knitr` and `kableExtra`

````
---
title: "Side by side"
output: html_document
---


```{r sample, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
t1 <- head(mtcars)[1:3]
t2 <- head(mtcars)[4:6]
```
## as list
```{r}
kable(list(t1, t2))
```

## with float
```{r, echo = FALSE}
kable(t1) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, position = "float_left")
kable(t2) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, position = "left")
```
````

It is intentional that table t2 gets `position = "left"`. If you allow it to float, this will not block the rest of the paragraph and mess up the following lines in your document.

**result**:

[image]

Comment: Any way to control each table width separately when displaying them side by side like you did?

Comment: @daniellga  haven't tried it, but check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61538273/7941188 - if it's useful, please kindly consider upvoting, too :) ( it's not mine!)

Comment: And this would work for either html or pdf document, right?

Comment: This solution doesn't work: the list option doesn't take options such as col.names for kable. And the float option doesn't put the tables side by side, they are still underneath. I presume this is down to the max-width of the page, but I can't see max width options on this one

Answer (score 9):

In [Quarto](https://quarto.org), you can use `layout-ncol`. This works both for HTML and PDF outputs.

````
---
title: "sidebyside"
format: pdf
---

```{r}
#| layout-ncol: 2
#| tbl-cap: "Tables"
#| tbl-subcap: ["A table", "Another table"]

library(knitr)

# table on the left
kable(head(mtcars))

# table on the right
kable(head(cars))
```
````

[image]

Comment: I somehow had an issue with subcaps on quarto with KableExtra objects. Strangely, putting a label like `#| label: tbl-example` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking off @Alex's answer since I don't have enough rep to leave a comment:

````
---
title: "sample"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
---

```{r}
library(knitr)
library(xtable)

t1 <- kable(head(mtcars)[1:3], format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE)
t2 <- kable(head(mtcars)[4:6], format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE)
```

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
```{r}
t1
```
\end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
```{r}
t2
```
\end{minipage}%
\end{table}
````

This will work instead of the `cat()` function call. In my experience, outputting LaTeX code from a code chunk will just lead to it getting printed as plain text in the PDF.