# Can three separate data.frames be aligned in htmlTable and RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am generating figures and reports using RMarkdown in .html format. I now wish to create three separate tables in the .html document but am unsure if I can create these. My `data.frame` consists of call logs, by differing locations and service roles. The amount of time (duration, in minutes) is also recorded. However, I have data on many workers so wish to subset by each worker's ID.

Can I create a row of three (subset, different data.frames) like this one in Excel?

[image]

My data.set is sensitive, so here is an example using R's inbuilt datasets and my RMarkdown code.

````
---
title: <center> <h1>Call Centre Report</h1> </center>
output:
 html_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
library("htmlTable")
htmlTable(subset(mtcars, gear=="4"),
          header =  paste(c("mpg", "cyl",
                            "disp", "hp", "drat",
                            "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")))
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
library("htmlTable")
htmlTable(subset(iris, Species=="setosa"),
          align="rrrr|r",
          header =  paste(c("Sepal Length", "Sepal Width",
                            "Petal Length", "Petal Width", "Species")))
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
library("htmlTable")
htmlTable(subset(chickwts, feed=="horsebean"),
          align="r|r",
          header =  paste(c("Weight", "Feed")))
```
````

Thank you.

Comment: [Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can subset a table in RMarkdown the same way you'd subset a table in R generally. There are several ways to subset so you just need to pick one that works best for you.

Comment: The subset issue is addressed and I have included an example. Please see my updated question regarding the multiple but aligned tables.

Comment: So this question is about side-by-side tables in Rmarkdown, not `subset`, right? Perhaps you should change the subject.

Comment: Thank you, title is edited.

Comment: I know it is not `htmlTable`, but if you are willing to go with other table-formatting functions, perhaps this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036680/align-multiple-tables-side-by-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a div element with the following style `<div style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between;">`

````
---
title: <center> <h1>Call Centre Report</h1> </center>
output:
 html_document
---
<div style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between;">
```{r echo=FALSE}
library("htmlTable")
htmlTable(subset(mtcars, gear=="4"),
          rnames = FALSE,
          header =  paste(c("mpg", "cyl",
                            "disp", "hp", "drat",
                            "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")))
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
library("htmlTable")
htmlTable(subset(iris, Species=="setosa"),
          align="rrrr|r",
          rnames = FALSE,
          header =  paste(c("Sepal Length", "Sepal Width",
                            "Petal Length", "Petal Width", "Species")))
```
```{r echo=FALSE}
library("htmlTable")
htmlTable(subset(chickwts, feed=="horsebean"),
          rnames = FALSE,
          align="r|r",
           header =  paste(c("Weight", "Feed")))
```
</div>
````

Comment: Thank you for the answer although this just creates a space between tables that are stacked vertically, which is not what I am after.

Comment: Are you using RStudio? Did you try to open the html document on a browser like chrome?

Comment: I was using RStudio, worked great in Chrome! Is there a way to reduce the space between tables, however?

Comment: You can use `<div style="display:flex; justify-content: flex-start;">`, but all the tables will be placed side by side without spaces.