# How can the backticks (`) printed around these tables be escaped?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

In [Align multiple tables side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036680/align-multiple-tables-side-by-side), a user asks about aligning tables, and the (very good) answer provided involves using latex in a chunk with the results returned as is to LaTeX. This is correct for that users question.

I am curious if this can be easily converted into an inline (i.e. not in chunk) solution.

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      \caption{}
      \centering,
       `r t1`,
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
        \caption{},
        `r t2`,
    \end{minipage} 
\end{table}
```

This is almost successful, however the backticks which are required to call the objects from R, end up also being printed to the output. What have I missed? Is it possible to escape the backticks from LaTeX, but not from the R process?

Update:
After requests for reproducibility, please see the [full markdown of my solution combined with the other answer I linked and referred to](https://pastebin.com/hMrwZRh2) as well as a [screencap of the output pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ozFa.jpg)

Comment: The top answer to the question you posted (and the accepted one) involved putting the tables in a list and calling kable. Did you try that as well? Are t1 and t2 data.frames?

Comment: In addition, you are probably better off putting it in an R chunk, setting the chunk to `results = 'asis'` and then calling `cat()` around the latex code, as in the question you linked.

Comment: @be_green, thanks for the advice. I think I fully understand the material in the question linked, and I have an existing solution in my use case implementing `results=as.is` in which the output functions fine. My interest is specifically limited to the implementation I describe, i.e. the inline application.

Comment: Oh ok, I misunderstood. Is this just curiosity or is there a separate use-case for this version?

Comment: Largely curiosity. It could be argued that if available this would be the preferred version due to simplicity, clarity, maintenance etc, but that's not my intent here either :)

Comment: @DaveRGP: [This code](https://pastebin.com/NN0Y02Pu) produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwwce.png), showing that the variables from R are read and printed as expected, even within a bunch of LaTeX code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem can't be reproduced in its current form.

Comment: @Werner, I've supplied a fuller reprex, and an example of the issue as an output. Apologies for the delay, I've been without a computer. Thanks for the suggestions :)

Comment: @DaveRGP: Your new code does not show any backticks. Instead, just like in your code currently visible in your post, you have a number of unnecessary `,` (after `\centering` and/or `\caption{}` and your in-line R statements). *These* are the things you see in your output, not backticks.

Comment: @Werner, thank you! I (stupidly) hadn't accounted for the original nature of the string I was editing having the commas to separate the items in `c()`, that was not needed when I modified it to inline. That's the answer. Happy to mark that as such if you submit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backticks are interpreted correctly, as is shown in the following example:

[image]

````
---
title: 'A title'
author: 'An author'
date: 'A date'
output: 
  pdf_document
---

```{r include=FALSE}
myvar1 <- 5 * cos(pi / 3)
myvar2 <- 10 * sin(pi / 6)
```

`myvar1` is `r myvar1`; `myvar2` is `r myvar2`.

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      \caption{}
      \centering
       `r myvar1`
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
        \caption{}
        `r myvar2`
    \end{minipage} 
\end{table}
````

In your example the backticks would also not be printed, but the `,`s you left as part of your code will be. You may have been mistaken by the `,`s looking like backticks.