# RMarkdown to PDF two gt() tables one next to the other

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, gt

I'm developing reports in RMarkdown to PDF.

I'm generating 2 tables using the following code:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: pdf_document
classoption: landscape
---

Blablabla

```{r include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(gt)
```
\newpage

```{r}
table_1 <- filter(cars,speed<10) %>% gt() %>% as_latex()
table_2 <- filter(cars,speed<10) %>% gt() %>% as_latex()
table_1
table_2
```
````

And I would like to get the 2 tables side by side on the same page.

Anybody a clue on how to do this?

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: What about a `kableExtra` solution? Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38039391/13249862

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LaTeX. Replace .5 before \textwidth with how wide you want each minipage to be as a proportion of the total page width.

````
```{r, results="asis"}

cat("\\begin{table}[h]
  \\centering
  \\begin{minipage}{.5\\textwidth}",
    table_1,
  "\\end{minipage}%
  \\begin{minipage}{.5\\textwidth}",
    table_2,
  "\\end{minipage}
\\end{table}")
```
````

[image]