# Displaying list of kable dataframes loses formatting

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I would like to display multiple tables side by side in Viewer/html. One way I found is using `kable` and specifying the list of datatables like so below, but the formatting is lost when a list of datatables are displayed versus displaying just a single datatable. Is there a way to retain `kable` formating and possibly add more formatting to make tables more differentiable with lines and spacing? Or is there another way to display side by side multiple tables in one Viewer/html besides `kable`? Thanks!

[Example with displaying multiple tables where formatting is lost:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK9GZ.png)

```
kable(list(head(cars), head(iris))) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

[Formatting retained when only one table is displayed:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NOFD.png)

```
kable(head(cars)) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036680/align-multiple-tables-side-by-side

Comment: The float option does help partly. However, I'm not working in`rmarkdown` , would it be possible to display the side by side float tables in a single Viewer or html file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `knitr::kables` to get two tables side by side in the Viewer. Further, it will also work for knitting to HTML (or saving as HTML from the RStudio Viewer).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

knitr::kables(list(
  kable(caption = "Left Table",
        head(cars)) %>% kable_styling(),
  kable(caption = "Right Table",
        head(iris)) %>% kable_styling()
)) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

Output

[image]

Comment: hi, @AndrewGb , what if we want one table upon the other ? (horizontaly) ?

Comment: @LarissaCury If you just need them above and below each other for knitting an RMarkdown, then you can just run the 2 tables as different statements rather than combining them, i.e., `kable(caption = "Left Table",  head(cars)) %>% kable_styling(); kable(caption = "Right Table", head(iris)) %>% kable_styling()`.

Comment: hi, @AndrewGB , thank you! the problem is that I have a lot of tables ( > 10) , that's why they're in the list... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73870622/plot-a-list-of-tables-vertically-kableextra-and-kable-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1 any ideas?