# r knitr kable padding not working with format = "html"

Tags: html, r, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to add padding to a table I am creating in an RMarkdown file that will generate both a pdf and an html flexdashboard. I know that there are a number of functions/packages I could use (pander, xtable, DT, etc.), but I would prefer to use the kable function from the knitr package.

The trouble I am having is that the padding argument does not seem to work. I would appreciate any help in solving this without having to add custom CSS to my document.

As a example, I have tried to run the code with padding set to 0, 10, 20 but the tables all look identical in the html file.

```
knitr::kable(head(cars), format = "html", padding = 0)
knitr::kable(head(cars), format = "html", padding = 10)
knitr::kable(head(cars), format = "html", padding = 20)
```

[image]

I am using knitr_1.14 and rmarkdown_1.0, and my session information is as follows.

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```

Comment: I don't see padding used in combinations with the format "html" in the examples. But based on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717323/align-two-data-frames-next-to-each-other-with-knitr you could try > kable(head(cars), format='html', table.attr='cellpadding="10"')

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Like Martin, I can't get the table.attr='cellpadding="10"' to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option `table.attr='cellpadding="20px"'` does not work for me. Using CSS styles and adding a class to the table with `table.attr='class="myTable"'` leads to all tables having the desired padding property (even if only one table carries the new class).

If I only want to modify one single table I usually go with jQuery:

````
---
title: "Table Cell Padding"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
knitr::kable(head(cars), format = "html")
```
```{r}
knitr::kable(head(cars), format = "html", table.attr='class="myTable"')
```
<style>
  .myTable td {
    padding: 40px;
  }
</style>
````

[image]

---

Another option is to use jQuery to edit individual elements. The following example modifies the table in the same way as the CSS styles above.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // When the document is fully loaded...
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // ... select the cells of the table that has the class 'myTable'
    // and add the attribute 'padding' with value '20px' to each cell
    $('table.myTable td').css('padding','20px');
  });
</script>
```

Here I add the class `myTable` to the table I want to modify. Afterwards I execute some JavaScript (see comments).
You could add any other CSS property to the table elements (or the table itself `$('table.myTable').css(...)`) in the same way (e.g. `$('table.myTable td').css('background-color','red');`)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid adding CSS or JavaScript, but it seems like this is the only way to overwrite the default table properties. Thanks for the example!