# How can I put multiple knitr::kable or stargazer tables next to each other?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, sweave, stargazer

Trying to simply produce separate tables of Anscombe's Quartet Sets, so that there is a nice space between them and formatting.  I'd prefer a 1x4 set of tables, but a 2x2 would suffice.

For either dimension of results, both `knitr::kable`s and `stargazer` solutions do not seem to be able to handle multiple non-model or non-summary objects:

```
anscombe.1 <- data.frame(X1 = anscombe[["x1"]], Y1 = anscombe[["y1"]], Set = "1")
anscombe.2 <- data.frame(X2 = anscombe[["x2"]], Y2 = anscombe[["y2"]], Set = "2")
anscombe.3 <- data.frame(X3 = anscombe[["x3"]], Y3 = anscombe[["y3"]], Set = "3")
anscombe.4 <- data.frame(X4 = anscombe[["x4"]], Y5 = anscombe[["y4"]], Set = "4")
# I usually call stargazer() with multiple model objects, so...
stargazer(anscombe.1, anscombe.2, anscombe.3, anscombe.4, summary = FALSE)
```

> Error in if (.global.summary[i] == TRUE) { : 
>         missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>       Calls:  ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> stargazer -> .stargazer.wrap

If call `stargazer(anscombe.1, summary = FALSE)`, however, I get the desired output. Similarly, I can call `knitr::kable(anscombe)` and get the table for a single set, but not all four:

```
knitr::kable(anscombe.1, anscombe.2, anscombe.3, anscombe.4)
```

> Quitting from lines 9-36 (anscombe.Rmd) 
>       Error in round(x[, j], digits[j]) :
>         non-numeric argument to mathematical function
>       Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval ->

How can I put these four sets together - preferably in a single row of four tables, with some space between them - so that I can line up their (similar) summary statistics below, likely using the same technique for a columnar summary?

Comment: You are really unclear about what kind of output you want.  Are you using knitr or Sweave?  Are you producing LaTeX or Markdown?  Nobody can answer your question without those details.

Comment: This may be what you are looking for [Align two data.frames next to each other with knitr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717323/align-two-data-frames-next-to-each-other-with-knitr). But I agree with @user2554330. It makes a difference whether you want to knit it to html or to latex.

Comment: @user2554330 I am compiling this in an rmd file with the doc_type set to pdf_document; so I am trying to knit latex using a call to stargazer or kable

Comment: @useR see my comment above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting things side-by-side in Markdown is hard:  it's not designed for that.  So you need to include some LaTeX markup in the file.

For example,

````
---
title: "Side by Side"
date: "October 31, 2016"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Side by Side

\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
```{r}
knitr::kable(diag(2), format = "latex")
```
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
```{r}
knitr::kable(diag(3), format = "latex")
```
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
```{r echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(diag(4), format = "latex")
```
\end{minipage}
````

This produces output like

[image]